# Get filepath File Open Dialog box cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsopenpanel

I have a File Open Dialog box in my application to select files from, but when the user clicks the 'Select' button in the box, it obviously won't do anything. How do I extract the filepath from the selected file? I need the filepath so I can get the contents of the file to encrypt. Initially, I hard coded the file I would use into my application, but that was only for testing purposes. Here is what I am using for the File Open Dialog Box:

```
int i;
NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
[openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];
[openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:YES];
[openDlg setPrompt:@"Select"];
NSString *fileName = [pathAsNSString lastPathComponent]; 
[fileName stringByDeletingPathExtension];
if ([openDlg runModalForDirectory:nil file:nil] == NSOKButton )
{
    NSArray* files = [openDlg filenames];
    for( i = 0; i < [files count]; i++ )
    {
        [files objectAtIndex:i];

    }

}
```

Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is already handling the files that the user has selected, you're just not doing anything with them.

The array returned from the `‑filenames` method contains the paths to the files that the user selected as `NSString` objects. If they have only selected one file, there will only be one object in the array. If they have selected no files, the array will be empty.

```
if ([openDlg runModalForDirectory:nil file:nil] == NSOKButton )
{
    NSArray* files = [openDlg filenames];
    for(NSString* filePath in [openDlg filenames])
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",filePath);
        //do something with the file at filePath
    }
}
```

If you only want the user to be able to select a single file, then call `[openPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection:NO]` when you're configuring the panel. That way, there will be a maximum of one entry in the `filenames` array.

As @VenoMKO points out, the `‑filenames` method is now deprecated and you should use the `‑URLs` method instead. This will return an array of file `NSURL` objects rather than an array of `NSString`s. Since pretty much all the file handling APIs in Snow Leopard were revised to take URLs, this would be the preferred option.

Comment: runModalForDirectory:file:types: is deprecated in OS X v10.6. You could use runModal instead. You can set path using setDirectoryURL:, and you can set fileTypes using setAllowedFileTypes:.

Answer (score 5):

Use `- (NSArray *)URLs` method instead of `filenames`.

Comment: When I am using -(NSArray *)URLs method, warning removed but i am not able to look into file to get file content.

SCENARIO :

-CASE 1
When am using, NSArray* files = [openDlg filenames];

I am getting this output : filePath = /Users/sumitgosh/Desktop/FD_TextFilesToUpload/SmallDummy Data/FirstName.txt
which is perfectly working in case of reading content of file.

-CASE 2 :
When am using, NSArray* files = [openDlg URLs];
OutPut : filePath = fileName = /Users/sumitgosh/Desktop/FD_TextFilesToUpload/SmallDummy Data/FirstName.txt
  
which is NOT working in case of reading content of file. @VenoMKO

Answer (score 0):

You Want to Get File Path Using Following Code

```
 NSOpenPanel* openPanel = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];
                [openPanel setCanChooseFiles:YES];
                [openPanel setCanChooseDirectories:NO];
                [openPanel setAllowsMultipleSelection: NO];
                [openPanel setAllowedFileTypes:ArrExtension ];
                if ([openPanel runModal] == NSOKButton ){

                   NSString *FilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[openPanel URL]];
                   [openPanel canHide];
                 }
```